# vue-create throws Vue packages version mismatch error

Tags: npm, vuejs2, vue-cli

After upgrading vue-cli when I tried executing `vue-create` I got an error regarding package mismatching.

> Vue packages version mismatch:
>
> - vue@2.5.22 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.js)
> - vue-template-compiler@2.6.10 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/vue-template-compiler/package.json)

**Anyone has knows how to fix this ?**

Answer (score 0):

Just manually update:

`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.js`

`Vue.version = '2.5.22';` with `Vue.version = '2.6.10';`